# Better formatting for description of tag badges

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, dupehammer

[image]

The site is all clean and beautiful, the formatting is great, the layout is organized... and we have this blue speech box like those on top of YouTube videos as the description box when you hover the mouse cursor over a tag badge with default font and a style that simply doesn't match the site.

Can this box be improved?

Comment: It's only for that specific place, the dupe hammer tag. (and it's a bug)